# QGIS Attribute table features changing when adding x,y,z coordinates

Tags: qgis

I have an attribute table with a few features, one of which is a Point # feature (i.e., 1,2,3,4,etc). When I went to add x,y,z coordinates to the attribute table, each time I added the x,y,z coordinate feature column, the Point #'s would change. I have 30 points in the layer identified under the Point # feature as 1-30. When I added the x coordinate feature the point #'s changed from 1-30 to 30-60 and then when I added the y cooridnate feature the point #'s changed from 30-60 to 60-90, and the same thing when adding z coordiantes. How can I prevent the Point #'s from changing?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. I personally don't understand what you mean. Could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Some screenshots of the attribute table (before/after) would be useful to add to your question. Also, how exactly are you adding "the x,y,z coordinate feature column"

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It sounds like you are using a datasource with out a fixed feature id (shapefile or CSV?) so when you change the feature attributes the old feature is deleted and a new one is added at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I collected some points out in the field in which I collected Point #, PE #, Description, and date and time. Back at the office I added x,y,z coordinates using the attribute table field calculator. When adding each new column for the respective coordiante, the value in the Point # column would automatically change. I want to add the x,y,z coordinates to my attribute table without anything else changing. I have added pictures to my original post